# Strange elm type error when instantiating a List of Svg msg elements in a record

Tags: elm

The following code:

```
import Svg exposing (..)
import Window exposing (..)


init_size : Model msg -> Size
init_size _ =
    { width = 800, height = 600 }


type alias Model msg =
    { extra_size : Int
    , size : Size
    , child_elements : List (Svg msg)
    }

init_renderSpace : Model msg
init_renderSpace model =
    { extra_size = 40
    , size = init_size model
    , child_elements = []
    }
```

, produces a strange error message that I can't really understand. Does anyone know what I did wrong?

this is the error message:

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ----------------------------------------------------- space.elm

The definition of `init_renderSpace` does not match its type annotation.

21| init_renderSpace : Model msg
22| init_renderSpace model =
23|>    { extra_size = 40
24|>    , size = init_size model
25|>    , child_elements = []
26|>    }

The type annotation for `init_renderSpace` says it is a:

    Model msg

But the definition (shown above) is a:

    Model msg
    -> { child_elements : List (Svg msg), extra_size : Int, size : Size }

Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.

Hint: The type annotation says there are NO arguments, but there is 1 argument
named in the definition. It is best practice for each argument in the type to
correspond to a named argument in the definition, so try that first!
```

Basically I'm trying to create a record which has a parameter that is basically a list of svg nodes. When I try to initialize the model with an empty list I get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that your type definition for `init_renderSpace` is `Model msg` but its implementation is `Model msg -> Model msg`. In other words, you are saying that `init_renderSpace` is a model, but it's actually a function that takes a model and returns a model.

Because you are not using any argument in `init_size`, I would remove the arguments from `init_size` and `init_renderSpace`:

```
init_size : Size
init_size =
    { width = 800, height = 600 }

init_renderSpace : Model msg
init_renderSpace =
    { extra_size = 40
    , size = init_size
    , child_elements = []
    }
```